# Kotlin: loading local html js into android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, android-webview

So I have a react-native project but decided to move away from it, the same reason why airbnb move to native development (java/kotlin). Most of my experience are web stuff so no mobile native experience other than hello world lol.

To cut the story short. Now, I want to use kotlin and wanted to salvage most of my code by loading all of it inside a WebView for now then maybe build more natively after as I gain more knowledge. (probably, 1 WebView component per activity/screen). And I probably need to convert my react-native code to react web but I think I got that covered.

My challenge would be calling/referencing native capabilities (eg. camera, local storage) in js to call a kotlin function or something like that but I think there are ways to do that but I haven't seen such example in kotlin so I'm struggling.

Summary:

- load local html/js files into WebView
- call/access native capabilities (eg. camera, local storage) from WebView

so far.. activity_main.xml

```
 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.kotlinwebview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.setSupportZoom(false)

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app/src/main/assets/test.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
<title>JavaScript Interface</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is HTML</h1>

    <script language="javascript">
       function someFunction() {
           ...
       }

       function someFunction2() {
           ...
       }

       function callFromActivity(msg){
           ...
       }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Would be cool if you guys can help me with the first one.

Comment: First problem solution :
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");

Comment: Okay thanks, do you know how to handle events in WebView as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // this is globar variable
    val FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1001
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.setSupportZoom(false)

        webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {

            override fun onShowFileChooser(
                webView: WebView,
                filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>,
                fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams
            ): Boolean {

                val contentSelectionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                contentSelectionIntent.type = "*/*"
                val intentArray: Array<Intent?> = arrayOfNulls(0)

                val chooserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent)
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File Chooser")
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray)
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
                return true
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            val result = if (intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK) null else data?.data
            result?.let {
                val uriArray: Array<Uri> = arrayOf(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry where should I put this code, I feel that it's under onCreate() ? if so, It seems I have a mismatch type with `WebChromeClient` and some Unresolved references

Comment: yea, so I got an unresolved reference for `webChromeClient` and `Intent` :(

Comment: Can you share your import statements

Comment: `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`

`import android.os.Bundle`

`import android.webkit.WebView`

`import android.webkit.WebViewClient`

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`

Comment: add these two
import android.webkit.*
import android.content.Intent

Comment: looks like it's okay now. Thanks! But I'm not sure what are those functions for? care to explain a bit? :)

Comment: yea, the android studio is not complaining anymore, but I actually don't know what's the code for? :|

Comment: If your problem is solve then please vote my answer. For more information please read this article.   https://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128&aaid=148